# Write data to file in exact milliseconds intervals (on Android)

Tags: android

I'm trying to write GPS location information to a file with Java (particularly in Android service handler thread) with exact time intervals and a millisecond resolution, e.g. every 1, 10 or 100 milliseconds...

I'd like to have entries as close as possible to the following example (for `dataWriteInterval=10ms`):

```
1493296800 location X=... Y=... Z=...
1493296810 location X=... Y=... Z=...
1493296820 location X=... Y=... Z=...
1493296830 location X=... Y=... Z=...
1493296840 location X=... Y=... Z=...
1493296850 location X=... Y=... Z=...
```

I've tried timer based approach (and earlier a simpler `Thread.sleep(delta)` based approach but I'm getting **more than 50% of writes at least 1 millisecond too late...**, e.g.:

```
1493296800 location X=... Y=... Z=...
1493296811 location X=... Y=... Z=...
1493296821 location X=... Y=... Z=...
1493296832 location X=... Y=... Z=...
1493296843 location X=... Y=... Z=...
1493296855 location X=... Y=... Z=...
```

I'm aware that Android is not a real-time OS but maybe someone could help me out with some hints on **how to increase writes accuracy here**?

E.g. maybe I can perform sleep with microseconds resolution and control the moment of writing with greater precision (it would be a kind of busy waiting though). Any suggestions?

```
    isRunning = true;
    final long dataWriteInterval = 10;
    class WriteTask extends TimerTask {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            long intervalEntryTimestamp = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
            // ...write current location with timestamp to file (or log)...
            // e.g. 'timestamp location X=... Y=... Z=...' assumming that I have current location object (or the latest one for that matter)
            long timestampAfterWrite = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
            long writeTook = timestampAfterWrite - intervalEntryTimestamp;
            long delta = dataWriteInterval - writeTook;

            if (isRunning && delta > 0) {
                writeTimer.schedule(new WriteTask(), delta);
            } else if (isRunning) {
                writeTrackingData(timestampAfterWrite); // we are short of time - write immediately and schedule next
                writeTimer.schedule(new WriteTask(), dataWriteInterval);
            }
        }
    };
    WriteTask dataWriteTask = new WriteTask();
    writeTimer.schedule(dataWriteTask, dataWriteInterval); // schedule first

    // Keep-alive (parent thread)
    while (isRunning) {
        try {
            Thread.yield();
            Thread.sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) { }
    }
```

Comment: Possibly naive suggestion, but if it's taking 10-11ms, try "asking" for 9ms. It will still be variable, but perhaps closer to what you want (I won't even ask why it matters _that much_ if you've got a ms-resolution timestamp against the readings...)

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: Thanks TripeHoun, this is what I'm currently doing too but I'm looking for something more analytical / reliable / predictive and less empiric based. Waiting 1ms less seems very CPU / system load dependent in this case and I feel that it may give unexpected results on a different devices.

Comment: About not asking the question, not an answer is that... It is a very firm and strict client requirement I got and a pressure here to have output files with equal intervals and 1 ms resolution. These files will be input to existing system that needs exact location probing times given. I don't see any solution for that without 'cheating' and tempering with actual timestamps (i.e. generating them vs just getting and writing) but I thought it's worth to try asking for some help / ideas / hints on SO first...